# Design first order linear differential equation solver using Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, circuit-design

[This link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-solve-differential-equations-using-op-amps.html) shows how to design a circuit that can solve a second order linear differential equation using Op-Amps. Can someone please suggest any way to do the same for a first order? Thanks!!

Comment: This is easy, do some research and google please. We ask questions related to design, make sure you do work first, then ask the question. Be specific and read the forum rules, otherwise your question will be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use almost the same circuit from the link on your question. If you look carefully you will see that there are **two** "Inverting Integrator" blocks, so it produces a **second** order equation. Then if you *remove* one integrator from the circuit, you will get a first order circuit. The rest of the theory is pretty much what is explained in your link.